# how can I retrieve the row number for the session?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a problem with my gridview in asp.net

I made the fields as hyperlink, I want to assign a number to every row as a session to refer to it in the next page

How could I retrieve the row numbers?

** I have a column that assign a number to every row, I don't know if that can help?

Answer (score 0):

2 potential solutions:

1) If you are using Hyperlinks, and not LinkButtons, add a query string parameter to the NavigateUrl of the Hyperlink.  When the link is clicked and user navigates to the second page, read that value using Request.QueryString.

2) If you are using LinkButtons with code-behind click handler, assign your number to the CommandArgument property and you will be able to access that value in the click handler.